# Proving the inradius (r) for an equilateral triangle

Tags: geometry, proof-explanation

[image]

I am trying to prove the basic properties of an equilateral triangle given in the image. I can do the first three, but am stumped at the fourth one.
Any hints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: We get the equation by summing up the areas:
$$\frac{1}{2}ar\cdot 3=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}a^2$$.Solve this equation for $$r$$

Comment: Where are you getting the equation on the left from?

Comment: Connecting the incircle center with $$A,B,C$$

Comment: $$r=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}a$$

Comment: Instead of a, do you mean s?

Comment: Yes instead of $s$ i have written $a$

Comment: That confused me a bit as a in this case was the altitude of the triangle

Comment: Ok $s$ is in Germany $$s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$$

Comment: I would say the same, but for some reason this diagram uses s to denote the side, but thanks, I actually understand this now.

Comment: Fine, so your problem is solved now?

Comment: Yes, although no doubt I will be asking about the other proofs (hopefully I can get them by myself though)

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The medians in a triangle  intersect at the centroid, which is located on each median at the $2/3$ of  the median length from the corresponding vertex.

Comment: This seems quite interesting, what do you mean by median, the midpoint? (I’m from the uk, so terminology may be different?)

Comment: I don't think so. They're the lines from each vertex to the midpoint of the opposite side.

Comment: Are these sort of facts things you are taught (if so at what level), do you just happen to pick them up (like I am now) or did you quickly research it?

Comment: I was taught them when I was a kid, around the age of 13-14  (more or less  year 9 in the U.K.).

Comment: So from this fact, where how do we get the answer? I was thinking since, the median is being split in 2/3 and 1/3, in this case r is 1/3 of the median and since we know the length of the median (a), we just do 1/3 multiplied by a.

Comment: It's exactly that. In some sense, it's a mid-school exercise ;o)